# Clickhouse calculate autoincrement

Tags: clickhouse

Exists legacy table with the integer identifier column.

Trying to reproduce autoincrement:

```sql
INSERT legacy_table (id, name)
SELECT
    (SELECT max(id) FROM legacy_table) + rowNumberInAllBlocks() id,
    name
FROM other_table
```

The problem is `SELECT max(id) FROM legacy_table` calculates one time and can spawn duplicates.

It is possible to execute `SELECT max(id)` per row or other solution for autoincrement ?

Comment: look at related discussion [Auto-increment column are not support #5681](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/5681)

Answer (score 1):

I would rely on array-functions to make behavior predictable.

Remarks:

- should not be any external inserts into target- and origin-tables
- should be run only one script at the time (so don't apply it to Distributed-table but sequentially execute on each shard)
- for the huge table, the nested query can fail so make sense add WHERE-clause to restrict the count of processed data

```sql
INSERT INTO target
SELECT result.1 AS id, result.2 AS name
FROM (
  WITH (SELECT max(id) FROM target) AS target_table_max_id
  SELECT 
    groupArray((id, name)) origin_data,
    arrayMap((origin_row, row_index) -> (target_table_max_id + row_index, origin_row.2), 
      origin_data, 
      arrayEnumerate(origin_data)) origin_data_updated,
    arrayJoin(origin_data_updated) result
  FROM origin);
```

Scripts to prepare test env:

```sql
# prepare test tables
CREATE TABLE target (`id` Int32, `name` String) ENGINE = Memory;
CREATE TABLE origin (`id` Int32, `name` String) ENGINE = Memory; 

# fill test tables 
INSERT INTO target 
SELECT  number AS id, toString(id) AS name
FROM numbers(8);

INSERT INTO origin 
SELECT number + 2048 AS id, toString(id) AS name
FROM numbers(4);
```